# Equivalent of window() function in Dev-C++

Tags: c++, dev-c++

I have been working on a C++ project in Turbo C++ sometime before. Now I've tried running the program in Dev-C++ and have managed to find equivalent functions for functions like `textcolor()` and `textbackground()`.  But I can't find a function which can do the task of `window()` in Turbo C++.

Can anyone mention a function which is similar to `window()` in Dev-C++?  Also can anyone tell me a function which will replace `gotoxy()` in Dev-C++?

Comment: Take a look into `ncurses` library.

Comment: From one ancient compiler to another ancient and horrible compiler.  Are you aware that today you can find compilers that are modern, free, more correct, and with friendlier error messages than either Turbo C++ or Decv C++?

Answer (score 0):

Dev-C++ is a quite outdated environment for MinGW. I dare to suggest you to change to a modern IDE, such as CodeBlocks:

http://www.codeblocks.org/

That said, and no matter what environment you use, provided you are using and updated c++ compiler, such as the one which comes with CodeBlocks, you can use conio2, a library replacement for Borland's conio,

http://conio.sourceforge.net/

Here is the documentation_

http://conio.sourceforge.net/docs/html/

If you are interested in your program being multiplatform, you could use this simple solution of mine:

http://webs.uvigo.es/jbgarcia/asignaturas/FP/lib/scrutil.zip

If you prefer a more complex library (more powerful, with a lot more possibilities), then you should choose ncurses, which has been ported to Windows:

http://www.projectpluto.com/win32a.htm

Hope this helps.